# Create a Divi child theme with custom php files in /core

Tags: php, wordpress, divi

I am looking to integrate SendFox (an email service like Mailchimp) into Divi. A friend wrote the necessary code but said he could only get it working in the parent theme. I have the files working in the parent theme (two files are needed in these locations - Divi/core/components/api/email/SendFox.php and Divi/core/_metadata.php)

I created these folders in the zip in my child theme, but it isn't recognized. I have the following basic functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles');

function enqueue_parent_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', 
        get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
}
```

I spoke with Divi devs, and they said that the child theme couldn't override the PHP files from the /core folder in the parent theme. Any ideas?

**Update**: To achieve this, two files are used, a modified _metadata.php (in /core) and SendFox.php (in /core/components/api/email)

_metadata.php code:

```
<?php
/* ====================================================================
 * ----->>> This file is automatically generated. DO NOT EDIT! <<<-----
 * ==================================================================== */
$metadata = '{"groups":{"api":{"path":"components/api","slug":"API","init":"components/api/init.php","members":["ElegantThemes","OAuthHelper","Service"]},"api/email":{"path":"components/api/email","slug":"API_Email","init":"components/api/email/init.php","members":["ActiveCampaign","Aweber","CampaignMonitor","ConstantContact","ConvertKit","Emma","Feedblitz","Fields","FluentCRM","GetResponse","HubSpot","iContact","Infusionsoft","MadMimi","MailChimp","MailerLite","MailPoet","Mailster","Ontraport","Provider","Providers","SalesForce","SendFox","SendinBlue"],"name_field_only":{"aweber":"Aweber","campaign_monitor":"CampaignMonitor","convertkit":"ConvertKit","getresponse":"GetResponse"}},"api/social":{"path":"components/api/social","slug":"API_Social","init":"","members":["Network"]},"api/spam":{"path":"components/api/spam","slug":"API_Spam","init":"components/api/spam/init.php","members":["SpamProvider","SpamProviders","ReCaptcha"]},"cache":{"path":"components/cache","slug":"Cache","init":"components/cache/init.php","members":["Directory","File"]},"data":{"path":"components/data","slug":"Data","init":"components/data/init.php","members":["ScriptReplacer","Utils"]},"lib":{"path":"components/lib","slug":"LIB","init":"","members":["BluehostCache","SilentThemeUpgraderSkin","WPHttp","OAuthBase","OAuthUtil","OAuthSignatureMethod","OAuthHMACSHA1","OAuthConsumer","OAuthToken","OAuthRequest"]},"mu-plugins":{"path":"components/mu-plugins","slug":"Mu-plugins","init":"","members":["SupportCenterSafeModeDisableChildThemes","SupportCenterSafeModeDisablePlugins"]},"post":{"path":"components/post","slug":"Post","init":"","members":["Object","Query","Taxonomy","Type"]}},"names":["ElegantThemes","ActiveCampaign","Aweber","CampaignMonitor","ConstantContact","ConvertKit","Emma","Feedblitz","Fields","FluentCRM","GetResponse","HubSpot","iContact","Infusionsoft","MadMimi","MailChimp","MailerLite","MailPoet","Mailster","Ontraport","SalesForce","SendFox","SendinBlue","OAuthHelper","Service","Network","EmailProvider","SpamProvider","EmailProviders","SpamProviders","ReCaptcha","Cache","Directory","File","CompatibilityWarning","ScriptReplacer","Utils","HTTPInterface","BluehostCache","SilentThemeUpgraderSkin","WPHttp","Logger","SupportCenterSafeModeDisableChildThemes","SupportCenterSafeModeDisablePlugins","PageResource","Portability","Object","Query","Taxonomy","Type","SupportCenter","SupportCenterMUAutoloader","Updates","VersionRollback","OAuthBase","OAuthUtil","OAuthSignatureMethod","OAuthHMACSHA1","OAuthConsumer","OAuthToken","OAuthRequest"],"slugs":["elegantthemes","activecampaign","aweber","campaign_monitor","constant_contact","convertkit","emma","feedblitz","fields","fluentcrm","getresponse","hubspot","icontact","infusionsoft","madmimi","mailchimp","mailerlite","mailpoet","mailster","ontraport","salesforce","sendfox","sendinblue","oauthhelper","service","network","email_provider","spam_provider","email_providers","spam_providers","recaptcha","cache","directory","file","compatibilitywarning","scriptreplacer","utils","httpinterface","bluehostcache","silentthemeupgraderskin","wphttp","logger","supportcentersafemodedisablechildthemes","supportcentersafemodedisableplugins","pageresource","portability","object","query","taxonomy","type","supportcenter","supportcentermuautoloader","updates","versionrollback","oauthbase","oauthutil","oauthsignaturemethod","oauthhmacsha1","oauthconsumer","oauthtoken","oauthrequest"],"ElegantThemes":"ET_Core_API_ElegantThemes","elegantthemes":"ET_Core_API_ElegantThemes","ET_Core_API_ElegantThemes":{"file":"components/api/ElegantThemes.php","groups":["api"],"name":"ElegantThemes","slug":"elegantthemes"},"ActiveCampaign":"ET_Core_API_Email_ActiveCampaign","activecampaign":"ET_Core_API_Email_ActiveCampaign","ET_Core_API_Email_ActiveCampaign":{"file":"components/api/email/ActiveCampaign.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"ActiveCampaign","slug":"activecampaign"},"Aweber":"ET_Core_API_Email_Aweber","aweber":"ET_Core_API_Email_Aweber","ET_Core_API_Email_Aweber":{"file":"components/api/email/Aweber.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"Aweber","slug":"aweber"},"CampaignMonitor":"ET_Core_API_Email_CampaignMonitor","campaign_monitor":"ET_Core_API_Email_CampaignMonitor","ET_Core_API_Email_CampaignMonitor":{"file":"components/api/email/CampaignMonitor.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"CampaignMonitor","slug":"campaign_monitor"},"ConstantContact":"ET_Core_API_Email_ConstantContact","constant_contact":"ET_Core_API_Email_ConstantContact","ET_Core_API_Email_ConstantContact":{"file":"components/api/email/ConstantContact.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"ConstantContact","slug":"constant_contact"},"ConvertKit":"ET_Core_API_Email_ConvertKit","convertkit":"ET_Core_API_Email_ConvertKit","ET_Core_API_Email_ConvertKit":{"file":"components/api/email/ConvertKit.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"ConvertKit","slug":"convertkit"},"Emma":"ET_Core_API_Email_Emma","emma":"ET_Core_API_Email_Emma","ET_Core_API_Email_Emma":{"file":"components/api/email/Emma.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"Emma","slug":"emma"},"Feedblitz":"ET_Core_API_Email_Feedblitz","feedblitz":"ET_Core_API_Email_Feedblitz","ET_Core_API_Email_Feedblitz":{"file":"components/api/email/Feedblitz.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"Feedblitz","slug":"feedblitz"},"Fields":"ET_Core_API_Email_Fields","fields":"ET_Core_API_Email_Fields","ET_Core_API_Email_Fields":{"file":"components/api/email/Fields.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"Fields","slug":"fields"},"FluentCRM":"ET_Core_API_Email_FluentCRM","fluentcrm":"ET_Core_API_Email_FluentCRM","ET_Core_API_Email_FluentCRM":{"file":"components/api/email/FluentCRM.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"FluentCRM","slug":"fluentcrm"},"GetResponse":"ET_Core_API_Email_GetResponse","getresponse":"ET_Core_API_Email_GetResponse","ET_Core_API_Email_GetResponse":{"file":"components/api/email/GetResponse.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"GetResponse","slug":"getresponse"},"HubSpot":"ET_Core_API_Email_HubSpot","hubspot":"ET_Core_API_Email_HubSpot","ET_Core_API_Email_HubSpot":{"file":"components/api/email/HubSpot.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"HubSpot","slug":"hubspot"},"iContact":"ET_Core_API_Email_iContact","icontact":"ET_Core_API_Email_iContact","ET_Core_API_Email_iContact":{"file":"components/api/email/iContact.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"iContact","slug":"icontact"},"Infusionsoft":"ET_Core_API_Email_Infusionsoft","infusionsoft":"ET_Core_API_Email_Infusionsoft","ET_Core_API_Email_Infusionsoft":{"file":"components/api/email/Infusionsoft.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"Infusionsoft","slug":"infusionsoft"},"MadMimi":"ET_Core_API_Email_MadMimi","madmimi":"ET_Core_API_Email_MadMimi","ET_Core_API_Email_MadMimi":{"file":"components/api/email/MadMimi.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"MadMimi","slug":"madmimi"},"MailChimp":"ET_Core_API_Email_MailChimp","mailchimp":"ET_Core_API_Email_MailChimp","ET_Core_API_Email_MailChimp":{"file":"components/api/email/MailChimp.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"MailChimp","slug":"mailchimp"},"MailerLite":"ET_Core_API_Email_MailerLite","mailerlite":"ET_Core_API_Email_MailerLite","ET_Core_API_Email_MailerLite":{"file":"components/api/email/MailerLite.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"MailerLite","slug":"mailerlite"},"MailPoet":"ET_Core_API_Email_MailPoet","mailpoet":"ET_Core_API_Email_MailPoet","ET_Core_API_Email_MailPoet":{"file":"components/api/email/MailPoet.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"MailPoet","slug":"mailpoet"},"Mailster":"ET_Core_API_Email_Mailster","mailster":"ET_Core_API_Email_Mailster","ET_Core_API_Email_Mailster":{"file":"components/api/email/Mailster.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"Mailster","slug":"mailster"},"Ontraport":"ET_Core_API_Email_Ontraport","ontraport":"ET_Core_API_Email_Ontraport","ET_Core_API_Email_Ontraport":{"file":"components/api/email/Ontraport.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"Ontraport","slug":"ontraport"},"ET_Core_API_Email_Provider":{"file":"components/api/email/Provider.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"Provider","slug":"provider"},"ET_Core_API_Email_Providers":{"file":"components/api/email/Providers.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"Providers","slug":"providers"},"SalesForce":"ET_Core_API_Email_SalesForce","salesforce":"ET_Core_API_Email_SalesForce","ET_Core_API_Email_SalesForce":{"file":"components/api/email/SalesForce.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"SalesForce","slug":"salesforce"},"SendFox":"ET_Core_API_Email_SendFox","sendfox":"ET_Core_API_Email_SendFox","ET_Core_API_Email_SendFox":{"file":"components/api/email/SendFox.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"SendFox","slug":"sendfox"},"SendinBlue":"ET_Core_API_Email_SendinBlue","sendinblue":"ET_Core_API_Email_SendinBlue","ET_Core_API_Email_SendinBlue":{"file":"components/api/email/SendinBlue.php","groups":["api","api/email"],"name":"SendinBlue","slug":"sendinblue"},"OAuthHelper":"ET_Core_API_OAuthHelper","oauthhelper":"ET_Core_API_OAuthHelper","ET_Core_API_OAuthHelper":{"file":"components/api/OAuthHelper.php","groups":["api"],"name":"OAuthHelper","slug":"oauthhelper"},"Service":"ET_Core_API_Service","service":"ET_Core_API_Service","ET_Core_API_Service":{"file":"components/api/Service.php","groups":["api"],"name":"Service","slug":"service"},"Network":"ET_Core_API_Social_Network","network":"ET_Core_API_Social_Network","ET_Core_API_Social_Network":{"file":"components/api/social/Network.php","groups":["api","api/social"],"name":"Network","slug":"network"},"EmailProvider":"ET_Core_API_Email_Provider","email_provider":"ET_Core_API_Email_Provider","SpamProvider":"ET_Core_API_Spam_Provider","spam_provider":"ET_Core_API_Spam_Provider","ET_Core_API_Spam_Provider":{"file":"components/api/spam/Provider.php","groups":["api","api/spam"],"name":"SpamProvider","slug":"spam_provider"},"EmailProviders":"ET_Core_API_Email_Providers","email_providers":"ET_Core_API_Email_Providers","SpamProviders":"ET_Core_API_Spam_Providers","spam_providers":"ET_Core_API_Spam_Providers","ET_Core_API_Spam_Providers":{"file":"components/api/spam/Providers.php","groups":["api","api/spam"],"name":"SpamProviders","slug":"spam_providers"},"ReCaptcha":"ET_Core_API_Spam_ReCaptcha","recaptcha":"ET_Core_API_Spam_ReCaptcha","ET_Core_API_Spam_ReCaptcha":{"file":"components/api/spam/ReCaptcha.php","groups":["api","api/spam"],"name":"ReCaptcha","slug":"recaptcha"},"Cache":"ET_Core_Cache","cache":"ET_Core_Cache","ET_Core_Cache":{"file":"components/Cache.php","groups":[],"name":"Cache","slug":"cache"},"Directory":"ET_Core_Cache_Directory","directory":"ET_Core_Cache_Directory","ET_Core_Cache_Directory":{"file":"components/cache/Directory.php","groups":["cache"],"name":"Directory","slug":"directory"},"File":"ET_Core_Cache_File","file":"ET_Core_Cache_File","ET_Core_Cache_File":{"file":"components/cache/File.php","groups":["cache"],"name":"File","slug":"file"},"CompatibilityWarning":"ET_Core_CompatibilityWarning","compatibilitywarning":"ET_Core_CompatibilityWarning","ET_Core_CompatibilityWarning":{"file":"components/CompatibilityWarning.php","groups":[],"name":"CompatibilityWarning","slug":"compatibilitywarning"},"ScriptReplacer":"ET_Core_Data_ScriptReplacer","scriptreplacer":"ET_Core_Data_ScriptReplacer","ET_Core_Data_ScriptReplacer":{"file":"components/data/ScriptReplacer.php","groups":["data"],"name":"ScriptReplacer","slug":"scriptreplacer"},"Utils":"ET_Core_Data_Utils","utils":"ET_Core_Data_Utils","ET_Core_Data_Utils":{"file":"components/data/Utils.php","groups":["data"],"name":"Utils","slug":"utils"},"HTTPInterface":"ET_Core_HTTPInterface","httpinterface":"ET_Core_HTTPInterface","ET_Core_HTTPInterface":{"file":"components/HTTPInterface.php","groups":[],"name":"HTTPInterface","slug":"httpinterface"},"BluehostCache":"ET_Core_LIB_BluehostCache","bluehostcache":"ET_Core_LIB_BluehostCache","ET_Core_LIB_BluehostCache":{"file":"components/lib/BluehostCache.php","groups":["lib"],"name":"BluehostCache","slug":"bluehostcache"},"OAuth":"ET_Core_LIB_OAuth","oauth":"ET_Core_LIB_OAuth","SilentThemeUpgraderSkin":"ET_Core_LIB_SilentThemeUpgraderSkin","silentthemeupgraderskin":"ET_Core_LIB_SilentThemeUpgraderSkin","ET_Core_LIB_SilentThemeUpgraderSkin":{"file":"components/lib/SilentThemeUpgraderSkin.php","groups":["lib"],"name":"SilentThemeUpgraderSkin","slug":"silentthemeupgraderskin"},"WPHttp":"ET_Core_LIB_WPHttp","wphttp":"ET_Core_LIB_WPHttp","ET_Core_LIB_WPHttp":{"file":"components/lib/WPHttp.php","groups":["lib"],"name":"WPHttp","slug":"wphttp"},"Logger":"ET_Core_Logger","logger":"ET_Core_Logger","ET_Core_Logger":{"file":"components/Logger.php","groups":[],"name":"Logger","slug":"logger"},"SupportCenterSafeModeDisableChildThemes":"ET_Core_Mu-plugins_SupportCenterSafeModeDisableChildThemes","supportcentersafemodedisablechildthemes":"ET_Core_Mu-plugins_SupportCenterSafeModeDisableChildThemes","ET_Core_Mu-plugins_SupportCenterSafeModeDisableChildThemes":{"file":"components/mu-plugins/SupportCenterSafeModeDisableChildThemes.php","groups":["mu-plugins"],"name":"SupportCenterSafeModeDisableChildThemes","slug":"supportcentersafemodedisablechildthemes"},"SupportCenterSafeModeDisablePlugins":"ET_Core_Mu-plugins_SupportCenterSafeModeDisablePlugins","supportcentersafemodedisableplugins":"ET_Core_Mu-plugins_SupportCenterSafeModeDisablePlugins","ET_Core_Mu-plugins_SupportCenterSafeModeDisablePlugins":{"file":"components/mu-plugins/SupportCenterSafeModeDisablePlugins.php","groups":["mu-plugins"],"name":"SupportCenterSafeModeDisablePlugins","slug":"supportcentersafemodedisableplugins"},"PageResource":"ET_Core_PageResource","pageresource":"ET_Core_PageResource","ET_Core_PageResource":{"file":"components/PageResource.php","groups":[],"name":"PageResource","slug":"pageresource"},"Portability":"ET_Core_Portability","portability":"ET_Core_Portability","ET_Core_Portability":{"file":"components/Portability.php","groups":[],"name":"Portability","slug":"portability"},"Object":"ET_Core_Post_Object","object":"ET_Core_Post_Object","ET_Core_Post_Object":{"file":"components/post/Object.php","groups":["post"],"name":"Object","slug":"object"},"Query":"ET_Core_Post_Query","query":"ET_Core_Post_Query","ET_Core_Post_Query":{"file":"components/post/Query.php","groups":["post"],"name":"Query","slug":"query"},"Taxonomy":"ET_Core_Post_Taxonomy","taxonomy":"ET_Core_Post_Taxonomy","ET_Core_Post_Taxonomy":{"file":"components/post/Taxonomy.php","groups":["post"],"name":"Taxonomy","slug":"taxonomy"},"Type":"ET_Core_Post_Type","type":"ET_Core_Post_Type","ET_Core_Post_Type":{"file":"components/post/Type.php","groups":["post"],"name":"Type","slug":"type"},"SupportCenter":"ET_Core_SupportCenter","supportcenter":"ET_Core_SupportCenter","ET_Core_SupportCenter":{"file":"components/SupportCenter.php","groups":[],"name":"SupportCenter","slug":"supportcenter"},"SupportCenterMUAutoloader":"ET_Core_SupportCenterMUAutoloader","supportcentermuautoloader":"ET_Core_SupportCenterMUAutoloader","ET_Core_SupportCenterMUAutoloader":{"file":"components/SupportCenterMUAutoloader.php","groups":[],"name":"SupportCenterMUAutoloader","slug":"supportcentermuautoloader"},"Updates":"ET_Core_Updates","updates":"ET_Core_Updates","ET_Core_Updates":{"file":"components/Updates.php","groups":[],"name":"Updates","slug":"updates"},"VersionRollback":"ET_Core_VersionRollback","versionrollback":"ET_Core_VersionRollback","ET_Core_VersionRollback":{"file":"components/VersionRollback.php","groups":[],"name":"VersionRollback","slug":"versionrollback"},"ET_Core_LIB_OAuthBase":{"file":"components/lib/OAuth.php","groups":["lib"],"name":"OAuth","slug":"oauth"},"ET_Core_LIB_OAuthUtil":{"file":"components/lib/OAuth.php","groups":["lib"],"name":"OAuth","slug":"oauth"},"ET_Core_LIB_OAuthSignatureMethod":{"file":"components/lib/OAuth.php","groups":["lib"],"name":"OAuth","slug":"oauth"},"ET_Core_LIB_OAuthHMACSHA1":{"file":"components/lib/OAuth.php","groups":["lib"],"name":"OAuth","slug":"oauth"},"ET_Core_LIB_OAuthConsumer":{"file":"components/lib/OAuth.php","groups":["lib"],"name":"OAuth","slug":"oauth"},"ET_Core_LIB_OAuthToken":{"file":"components/lib/OAuth.php","groups":["lib"],"name":"OAuth","slug":"oauth"},"ET_Core_LIB_OAuthRequest":{"file":"components/lib/OAuth.php","groups":["lib"],"name":"OAuth","slug":"oauth"}}';
```

**And here is the code for SendFox.php:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Wrapper for SendFox's API.
 *
 * @since   1.1.0
 *
 * @package ET\Core\API\Email
 */
class ET_Core_API_Email_SendFox extends ET_Core_API_Email_Provider {

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public $BASE_URL = 'https://api.sendfox.com';

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public $name = 'SendFox';

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public $slug = 'sendfox';

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public $uses_oauth = false;

    public function __construct( $owner, $account_name, $api_key = '' ) {

        parent::__construct( $owner, $account_name, $api_key );

        $this->_maybe_set_custom_headers();
    }

    protected function _maybe_set_custom_headers() {

        if ( empty( $this->custom_headers ) && isset( $this->data['api_key'] ) ) {

            $this->custom_headers = array( 
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->data['api_key'],
            );
        }
    }

    public function get_account_fields() {

        return array(
            'api_key' => array(
                'label' => esc_html__( 'API Key', 'et_core' ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function get_data_keymap( $keymap = array(), $custom_fields_key = '' ) {

        $keymap = array(
            'list'       => array(
                'list_id'           => 'id',
                'name'              => 'name',
                'subscribers_count' => 'subscribed_contacts_count',
            ),
            'subscriber' => array(
                'email'      => 'email',
                'name'       => 'first_name',
                'last_name'  => 'last_name',
            ),
        );

        return parent::get_data_keymap( $keymap, $custom_fields_key );
    }

    public function fetch_subscriber_lists() {

        if ( empty( $this->data['api_key'] ) ) {

            return $this->API_KEY_REQUIRED;
        }

        if ( empty( $this->custom_headers ) ) {

            $this->_maybe_set_custom_headers();
        }

        /**
         * The maximum number of subscriber lists to request from SendFox's API.
         * One page = 10 lists.
         *
         * @since 2.0.0
         *
         * @param int $max_lists
         */

        $max_lists = (int) apply_filters( 'et_core_api_email_sendfox_max_lists', 20 );

        $url = "{$this->BASE_URL}/lists";

        $this->prepare_request( $url, 'GET', false, array() );

        $this->response_data_key = 'data';

        // $this->request->data_format = 'body';

        $result = parent::fetch_subscriber_lists();

        // bf_log( array( 'page' => 1, 'result' => $result, 'data' => $this->data ) );

        $lists = $this->data['lists'];

        if ( $max_lists > 10 )
        {
            $count_pages = absint( $max_lists / 10 );

            for ( $i = 2; $i <= $count_pages; $i++ )
            {
                $url = "{$this->BASE_URL}/lists?page={$i}";

                $this->prepare_request( $url, 'GET', false, array() );

                $this->response_data_key = 'data';

                // $this->request->data_format = 'body';

                $result = parent::fetch_subscriber_lists();

                // bf_log( array( 'page' => $i, 'result' => $result, 'data' => $this->data ) );

                foreach( $this->data['lists'] as $id => $list )
                {
                    if( !empty( $list['list_id'] ) )
                    {
                        $lists[ $id ] = $list;
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->data['lists'] = $lists;

            // bf_log( array( 'final_data' => $this->data ) );

            $this->save_data();
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function subscribe( $args, $url = '' ) {

        $list_id   = $args['list_id'];

        $args      = $this->transform_data_to_provider_format( $args, 'subscriber', array( 'list_id' ) );

        $url       = "{$this->BASE_URL}/contacts";

        $email     = $args['email_address'];

        $err       = esc_html__( 'An error occurred, please try later.', 'et_core' );

        $ip_address = 'true' === self::$_->array_get( $args, 'ip_address', 'true' ) ? et_core_get_ip_address() : '0.0.0.0';

        $args['lists'] = array( intval( $list_id ) );

        unset( $args['list_id'] );

        if ( empty( $this->custom_headers ) ) {

            $this->_maybe_set_custom_headers();
        }

        $this->prepare_request( $url, 'POST', false, $args, true );

        $result = parent::subscribe( $args, $url );

        if ( 'success' !== $result )
        {
            $result = $err;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't override core files from source of child theme, but you can use action hooks to get your code running from child theme.

Please show us the code from sendfox, so we can help to integrate it

**Update**: you can include the SendFox.php ion your child theme's functions.php, this class extend the original class from divi.

but you can't override or change the _metadata.php, this file is autogenerated, so you must find hooks or filters to insert data in generation process.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've updated my post with the code.

Comment: thanks - it sounds like adding the SendFox.php should be a piece of cake; I could just create a simple functions.php and paste that code in.  Honestly, I am at a bit of a loss as to step two, especially given that this this is autogenerated, what would it mean whenever the parent theme is updated? (which is the problem that I have now)

Comment: Have spoken to my friend. Looks like creating a plugin is the best solution at this point. Thank you for your help!